# Writing a special character in HTML

Tags: html, css, special-characters

I'd like to add a special caracter like `é` or `à`

```
<strong class="b2">d&eacute;di&eacute;e &agrave;</strong>
```

the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/cufon-replace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/Open_Sans_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/Open_Sans_Light_300.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="~/Content/js/Open_Sans_Semibold_600.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/tms-0.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/tms_presets.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Content/js/FF-cash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body id="page1">
<!-- header -->
    <div class="bg">
        <div class="main">
            <header>
                <div class="row-1">
                    <h1>
                        <img src="~/Images/logo1.jpg" class="logo" href="index.html"></img>
                        <strong class="slog">The most creative ideas</strong>
                    </h1>

                </div>
                <div class="row-2">
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="menu">
                          <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>
                          <li><a href="news.html">Our News</a></li>
                          <li><a href="services.html">Our Services</a></li>
                          <li><a href="products.html">Our Products</a></li>
                          <li class="last-item"><a href="contacts.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="row-3">
                    <div class="slider-wrapper">
                        <div class="slider">
                          <ul class="items">
                            <li><img src="~/Content/images/slider-img1.jpg" alt="">
                                <strong class="banner">
                                    <strong class="b1">AkoPlus</strong>
                                    <strong class="b2">Propose</strong>
                                    <strong class="b3">des formations à la carte en fonction de <br> votre besoin</strong>
                                </strong>
                            </li>
                            <li><img src="~/Content/images/slider-img2.jpg" alt="">
                                <strong class="banner">
                                    <strong class="b1">notre objectif est</strong>
                                    <strong class="b2">d&eacute;di&eacute;e &agrave;</strong>
                                    <strong class="b3">offrir des  services  en utilisant<br>les normes les plus &eacute;lev&eacute;es</strong>
                                </strong>
                            </li>
                            <li><img src="~/Content/images/slider-img3.jpg" alt="">
                                <strong class="banner">
                                    <strong class="b1">encourage</strong>
                                    <strong class="b2">Business</strong>
                                    <strong class="b3">Success and growth with our<br>professionals of this sphere</strong>
                                </strong>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <a class="prev" href="#">prev</a>
                          <a class="next" href="#">prev</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
```

But it didn't work. it's displays empty. Why this happens? How can i fix it?

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/pL9ST/

Comment: Do u have a charset defined in your HTML?

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: @koningdavid — Shouldn't make a difference. The only **literal** characters in the HTML are ASCII.

Comment: @Lamloumi: Can you post *all* of the relevant code?

Comment: Still works for me: http://jsbin.com/ofopos/1/edit

Comment: Do you *really* want to fiddle around with &uuml;nreadable &eacute;ntities? No. Learn how to [Handle Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll go out on a limb and guess that the special *font* being used does not contain these characters.

Comment: i have this `Cufon.replace('.b1', { fontFamily: 'Open Sans', hover:true });` and `.b1 {color:#0f0f0f;font-size:50px;line-height:1.2em;display:block;letter-spacing:-3px}`. did it had relation with this error?

Comment: Probably yes. Get rid of the font replacing or really inspect the font you are using; it likely doesn't include those characters.